# Drying up a dynamicexpression in C# 4.0

Tags: c#

I have the following code, I want to refactor the duplication out of:

```
    public bool HasBia
    {
        get 
        {
            if (IsC2User())
            {
                return true;
            }

            if(_hasBia == null)
            {
                _hasBia = _excludes.HasBia; 
            }

            return _hasBia.Value;
        }
    }

    public bool HasTeachAndTest
    {
        get
        {
            if (IsC2User())
            {
                return true;
            }

            if(_hasTeachAndTest == null)
            {
                _hasTeachAndTest = _excludes.HasTeachAndTest;
            }

            return _hasTeachAndTest.Value;
        }
    }
```

The bit I am having trouble with is that, _excludes.HasBia and _excludes.HasTeachAndTest are dynamic expressions or dynamic properties that are resolved by TryGetMember of a class that inherits from DynamicObject.

I think I want to do something like this:

```
public bool HasPermission(bool? value, DynamicExpression expression)
{
    if (IsC2User())
    {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Then I can call it like this:

```
return HasPermission(_hasBia, _excludes.HasTeachAndTest);
```

But I am unsure how to invoke the expression when it is passed into the HasPermission method.

Anybody got any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by `drying`?

Comment: @leppie: [don't repeat yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Comment: Why are you using dynamic objects?

Comment: @Jeff M: Thanks, for a moment I thought you were taking me for a ride  ;P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this would work.

```
public bool HasPermission(ref bool? field, bool defaultValue)
{
    if (IsC2User())
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (field == null)  //lazy loading a bool? overkill?  :)
    {
        field = defaultValue;
    }
    return field;
}

//usage
public bool HasBia
{
    get 
    {
        return HasPermission(ref _hasBia, _excludes.HasBia);
    }
}
```

Or if there are side effects of retrieving the default value

```
public bool HasPermission(ref bool? field, Func<bool> getDefaultValue)
{
    if (IsC2User())
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (field == null)
    {
        field = getDefaultValue();
    }
    return field;
}

//usage
public bool HasTeachAndTest
{
    get
    {
        return HasPermission(ref _hasTeachAndTest, () => _excludes.HasTeachAndTest);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the point of the `ref` if you dont re-assign it (and the fact that you are possible returning it)?

Comment: @leppie: Ah yes, I left out an assignment there.  But on second thought, it's better to explicitly test for null.

Comment: Or you can go `ugly`: `field = (field ?? getDefaultValue())`  :)

Comment: @leppie: I thought about that but then an assignment would always take place when it really isn't necessary.  That was my original intention.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it makes any sense to remove this sort of duplication, consider the additional complexity introduced by any of the possible solutions vs. the simplicity of repeating a pattern at two places.

Perhaps what you are really missing is a concept in your problem domain that you are trying to come by with duplication in your solution domain. Jeff M's solution is fine in regards to a technical implementation, but I'd not use it in this simple case.